# SABR vs Dupire: when to use what?

Tags: local-volatility, sabr, sabr-model

I was wondering for which products one would use the (AF)SABR model and for which ones Dupire's Local Volatility model.

If I understand correctly, Dupire is by construction Arbitrage-Free but produces an unrealistic smile. On the other hand, SABR seems to give a more realistic smile but might produce arbitrage.
With these considerations at hand, which family of products would one price with SABR and which one with Dupire? Can someone give an idea of what are the "trending" market practices (and some reference would be great there!)?

Also, how do AFSABR and Dupire with stochastic volatility compare? My impression is that they should ameliorate the problem of their respective "classical" versions but, if so, how would one choose when to use what?